# Getting valid React CSSProperties names at runtime

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, browser

I'd like to make a dropdown which would allow someone to select a camelized CSS Property(e.g. width, color, textAlign) for an inline style in React.

Rather than manually populate the whole dropdown, it occurred to me that if I could somehow use the `React.CSSProperties` type as a value, then I wouldn't need to hard code anything myself. I'm not sure if such a thing is possible though.

Or perhaps there is another way of accessing the names of these properties which I am not aware of?

Comment: It's not possible. TypeScript does not exist at runtime. What you can do is loop over `document.body.style`'s keys, though you'll get different ones depending on what browser you run it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this data: https://github.com/mdn/data/tree/master/css.

The library csstype gets the data from there and builds the type information from it. You could also use it at runtime if you transform the data in a build step to your needs.

If you don't need to validate the values or don't need to know the specific browser properties, then you can just use `document.body.style` like answered in the comment from @Sergiu Paraschiv.

Comment: Thats one beefy list. Ya I suppose I'll just hardcode a few and call it a day. Thanks!

Comment: Haha right..in most cases that would be the best option.